# How can I change a ko.observabel with durandal from another view?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, durandal

So basically what I want to do is this:

main.html:

```
   <div style="cursor:pointer" data-bind="compose: {model: $data, view: "child.html"}" />
   <div style="background-color:#CCC; cursor:pointer; width:45px; " data-bind="visible: selectedlist ().length > 0">something</div>
```

main.js:

```
   self.selectedlist = ko.observableArray([]);
   self.addfnc = function(){self.selectedlist().add;}
```

child.html:

```
  <div data-bind="click: addfnc()">ADD</div>
```

It calls the function and adds it to the list but at the main.html nothing changes. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you add the new stuff to the result of the observableArray, not the observableArray itself. When you want to update the underlying ko.observableArray you have to do

```
self.selectedlist.push('Whatever')
```

For info regarding manipulating knockout arrays take a look at [their documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)

Comment: Man you saved my life. I really thought that it is going to be a more complicated problem. Thank you very much.